# Is it possible to compare a Char* to a string variable?

Tags: c++

For our assignment at school, we have to store 2.3 million passwords into a dynamic char. I have to check the user's password against all of these passwords to make sure it is not on the list.

If the user's password is on the list, they lose a point on the strength of their password.

I have tried this:

```
int i = 1, maxSize = 2300000, passwordList = 1;

char* passCommon = NULL;
passCommon = new char[mazSize];

string password = "JohnDoe";     // Use this for example.

for (i=0; i > maxSize; i++)
{ 
  if(password == passCommon[i])
  {
    passwordList = 0;
    break;
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use strcmp for comparing `char*` otherwise you are checking the pointers for equality not the strings stored at those addresses

Comment: Just use a `std::unordered_set<std::string>` for the set of common passwords.

Comment: Unrelated, that loop is never going to work regardless. The comparator is backwards.

Answer (score 0):

First, you dynamically create an old-fashioned string:

```
passCommon = new char[mazSize];
```

One string, not many. If you want to create an array of zero-strings, you should use:

```
char **passCommon = nullptr;
```

Note two asterisk, not only one. Asterisks should be near identifircator. Then you should dynamically create an array of `char *` (pointers to char arrays). Then you should loop througn this array and on each iteration dynamically create an array of char that is assigned to pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry about my English is poor, but I hope I can do something useful for you.
I think you can store 2.3 million passwords in container of string(such as vector), And you can comparing them like :  `password == passCommon[i]`